# Trouble with htaccess mod_rewrite and directories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've read dozens of posts about similar problems, but I can't get this one figured out.

I have SEO friendly URL's on my site that look like this...

```
http://www.website.com/tequila/bottle-name.html
http://www.website.com/whiskey/bottle-name.html
http://www.website.com/vodka/bottle-name.html
```

...where bottle-name is the actual name of the bottle.

I am doing a mod_rewrite to a PHP handler to actually deliver the pages.  Each handler is located in each directory (tequila, vodka, whiskey).

The first one (tequila) is working, but the other two are not and I can't figure out why.

Here is the mod_rewrite code I have right now...

```
#Rewrite seo urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tequila/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?liquor=$1&liquor-type=tequila [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/whiskey/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?liquor=$1&liquor-type=whiskey [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/vodka/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?liquor=$1&liquor-type=vodka [L]
```

What appears to be happening is the whiskey and vodka pages are getting caught and processed by the tequila mod_rewrite (guessing because it is first in the list here).

So, http://www.website.com/vodka/vodka-bottle.html is actually getting rewritten as http://www.website.com/tequila/index.php?liquor=vodka-bottle.html&liquor-type=tequila.

It seems like I haven't setup the RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tequila/ correctly?

Any help or pointers anyone can provide are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I may have missed something... why are you negating the `^/tequila/`? The `!` will cause a match on all **other** liquor types, rather than the one you list.

Comment: Ahhhh...that did it! Problem is my inexperience with all this and copying/pasting code from someone else's solution.  If you can put that comment/solution in an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted solution.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Added as an answer. Also, you're welcome :) - I am mostly self-taught by pulling apart other code, so I feel your frustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you negating the `^/tequila/?` The `!` will cause a match on all other liquor types, rather than the one you list.